# Using SSL Generates HTTP Error 400. The Request URL is Invalid

Tags: ssl, post, https

My question is what could cause a server response of HTTP Error 400. The Request URL is Invalid for a HTTPS request but not for a HTTP request?

This error is only present when making a POST using HTTPS. The same message using HTTP works fine. I control both the client and server application in this example.

On the Server side I have a simple .NET Windows Service HTTPListener with a "https://*:443" prefix

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
            listener.Prefixes.Add("https://*:443/");
            listener.Start();
```

*I know I said HTTP works while HTTPS doesn't. For this example I removed the http prefix in cause you're wondering*

The client side I'm using WFetch for testing.

This is the request that is generating the error:

```
POST  HTTP/1.0
Content-type: text/xml
Content-length: 1505
host: somewhere.com:443

<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<cXML version="1.1.007" xml:lang="en-US" payloadID="1234" timestamp="2016-02-05T02:16:31-05:00">...</cXML>
```

I've tried various things that seem to work, (i.e. using HTTP instead of HTTPS and using a .NET application I wrote to make a HttpWebRequest). The problem is the client side is set in stone. The request above can't be modified a whole lot. That's why I'm trying to understand why the current request is generating this error and possibly what has to change on the server side to accommodate this request.

One a side note, if I reduce the request down to just a single line:

```
POST  HTTP/1.0
```

It generates the same error. So I'm not sure if there is a security certificate mismatch (or if that would even be the error it generates if there was). I appreciate any help in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At www.w3.org, [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) states:

> **400 Bad Request:** The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

I believe that your petition lacks the URL:

```
POST /my-url HTTP/1.0
```

Comment: That took care of it. Now to figure out why the client request wouldn't have one, but that's for another day.